# pip install scikit-learn error

Tags: python, pip

the error is

```
Command "c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe - 
u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
bnoak8r5\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-4yww_x3p\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
install-bnoak8r5\scikit-learn\
```

on the website its says this

```
Python (>= 2.7 or >= 3.3),
NumPy (>= 1.8.2),
SciPy (>= 0.13.3).
```

i have python 3.7 
numpy 1.14.3 and scipy 1.1.0

so is my python version to new along with my scipy version?

when i download the file and try to install it i get this error

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-6eptglns\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you download Anaconda and use conda install as your package manager for numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, etc. I can't guarantee it will fix this problem but it most certainly will be better at what you are using scikit-learn for. It would certainly change this error because it downloads a new installation of python somewhere else within anaconda's directories. Doing this has fixed this same problem for some people in the past.

I hope this helps.